# AT&T Assembly how to compare Strings from console

Tags: string, assembly, att

I have the string "-l" stored in a variable called lineSpace and I want to check if its equal to a value which I get from the console arguments.

I try to get the first part of the argument and then I compare it to the value stored in the variable. If I debug the code, they seem to share the same value but sadly it never takes the jump.

```
.data
lineSpace: .ascii "-l"

_start:
movl 8(%esp), %esi
movl (%esi), %eax
movl lineSpace, %ebx
cmpl %eax, %ebx
je ...
```

Comment: Your code loads and compares 4 bytes but your string is only 1 byte.  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @fuz i dont know Im new at assembly. Should i try normal mov and cmp instead of movl/cmpl?

Comment: A string is a sequence of bytes.  You should compare them *byte* by *byte*.   Use byte-sized loads and comparison operations.  If you can use the libc, you can also use the `strcmp` function to do the job.

Comment: Your string is actually 2 bytes, not zero-terminated (you used `.ascii` rather than `.asciiz`).  You could compare it with `cmpw linespace, %ax`.  Or `cmpw $0x6c2d, (%esi)` to compare 2 bytes in memory against a 2-byte immediate.  (Unfortunately GAS doesn't let you write `$'-l'` the way NASM would for a multi-characters literal with a numeric value that is those characters in little-endian order.)  But you don't want to compare just 2 bytes, you want to check that argv[1] has a terminating 0 after the `-l`, unless you want `-lfoobar` to work the same as `-l`.

Comment: It's the same as you'd write in C without strict-aliasing: you could call `strcmp` or `memcmp`, or you could manually compare a `short` and a byte (C `char` if we're talking about C compiling for x86).

Comment: @PeterCordes thank your for explaining that really helped me. Sadly i can't get cmpw to work, but you gave me a good hint how to solve my problem!